# Cygwin is not working very well in netbeans 7

Tags: netbeans, terminal, cygwin, filepath

The terminal in netbeans doesn't show which directory I'm in unlike in cygwin where the current file path is displayed in color. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you, and I found that I can run the Cygwin's bash.exe in NetBeans' terminal and then initial the ~/.bash_profile in that terminal as same as running in Cygwin.
    For example,

```
/usr/bin/bash.exe
```

and then

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```